# How can i use FLUID / extbase for preview at the backend of custom content elements TYPO3 >= 11

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, custom-backend

How can I use FLUID / extbase for backend preview of custom content elements in the backend page module (TYPO3 >= 11) since the class "PageLayoutView" is deprecated (for example  "PageLayoutViewDrawItem" hook)?

I know this new method, but it doesn't use FLUID and I have to write my own database queries (e. g. querybuilder):
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/CustomBackendPreview.html

I don't understand if there is any way to get the same "magic" extbase stuff for the backend working like it does for the frontend (for one and the same content-element)?!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a Fluid template for the backend preview in the page TSConfig.

```
mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.mycustomctype = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/CTypePreview.html
```

If you want to render images in the preview, you need the vhs-ViewHelper "v:resource.record.fal".